# Where to place a single setting?

Tags: android, guidelines, settings

I'm working on an Android app which, for the moment, only has a single setting. It fits all the android guidelines requirements for "make it a setting".

Should I follow the guidelines and make an option in the overflow menu that then goes to a screen that has that single setting (knowing more may follow in the future) or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 4):

If it’s a permanent setting, so it’s unlikely that users would change it regularly, add it to the settings menu.

A user that opens the settings menu and only finds a single setting would hardly be confused (let alone bothered *). Less time configuring, more fun.

There is also some value in definitely knowing that there is only one setting. No need to look somewhere else, in uncommon places, because there is a settings menu, so if there were more settings available, they would be contained in this menu.

(* unless important/desired settings are missing, that is ;-))

Comment: I guess even if it's just one it does make sense for it to be where Android users are accustomed to find them, yeah. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the setting. If it's something small like a toggle button or a button that might bring up a dialog, maybe you can incorporate it on a relevant screen. If it's more than that, I would follow the guidelines and place it in the menu.

Comment: As a single setting it feels like overkill; anywhere else it's just out of place, that's the dilemma.

As for size, it fits a single line item with a checkbox

Comment: There are two alternatives. One is to place it in the menu, the other - on a screen. I suggested a rationale that might help you decide between the two. You're saying that neither option suits you. So what kind of answer were you looking for? :) BTW a third option is to try and drop the setting or turn it into an integral part of a screen.